# Net_Geo Pear Package in PHP

Tags: php, ip, pear

I have installed the Net_Geo pear package on my PHP Server.

This is the code I am using,

getRecord($ip);

    // output
    echo "Single IP results:
";
    echo "

```
";
    print_r($results);
    echo "
```

";

    // example array of multiple IPs
    $arr_ips = array
    (
      gethostbyname("www.google.com"),
      gethostbyname("www.heise.de"),
      gethostbyname("www.college.ch")
    );

    // fetch information array from net_geo
    $results = $net_geo->getRecord($arr_ips);

    // output
    echo "Multiple IP results:
";
    echo "

```
";
    print_r($results);
    echo "
```

";

?>

But this piece of code is not displaying any results.
 I think this code is not working at all.

This is the Net_Geo Object

Net_Geo Object
(
    [cache_path] => /tmp/
    [cache_ttl] => 30
    [default_timeout] => 60
    [default_caida_server] => http://netgeo.caida.org/perl/netgeo.cgi
    [default_hostip_server] => http://api.hostip.info/
    [localizer_data] => ./demo.csv
    [service] => 
    [cache_prefix] => netgeo
    [useragent] => PHP/NetGeo
    [useragent_version] => 1.0
    [array_limit] => 100
    [cache] => Cache_Function Object
        (
            [expires] => 2592000
            [caching] => 1
            [gc_time] => 1
            [gc_probability] => 1
            [gc_maxlifetime] => 86400
            [container] => Cache_Container_file Object
                (
                    [fileLocking] => 
                    [cache_dir] => /tmp/
                    [filename_prefix] => netgeo
                    [entries] => Array
                        (
                        )

```
                [total_size] => 0
                [max_userdata_linelength] => 257
                [preload] => 1
                [id] => 
                [group] => 
                [expires] => 0
                [cachedata] => 
                [userdata] => 
                [unknown] => 1
                [encoding_mode] => base64
                [highwater] => 2048000
                [lowwater] => 1536000
                [allowed_options] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => encoding_mode
                        [1] => highwater
                        [2] => lowwater
                    )

                [group_dirs] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [_debug] => 
        [_default_error_mode] => 
        [_default_error_options] => 
        [_default_error_handler] => 
        [_error_class] => PEAR_Error
        [_expected_errors] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[netgeo_global] => netgeo_global
[useragent_string] => 
[default_server] => 
[last_target] => 
[applicationName] => 
[alternateServerUrl] =>
```

)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page of [`Net_Geo::Net_Geo()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-geo.net-geo.php) says that :

The method accepts two parameters :

```
bool Net_Geo() ( string $applicationName = '' , string $alternateServerUrl = '' )
```

And those parameters are :

- `string $applicationName` - *Optional* application name to use in UserAgent when polling Netgeo
- `string $alternateServerUrl` - URL to Netgeo service script, will be set to "http://netgeo.caida.org/perl/netgeo.cgi" unless changed

You are not passing any of those parameters -- which means the default Netgeo service URL is used...

... And if you try to open it ( http://netgeo.caida.org/perl/netgeo.cgi ), you'll see it doesn't work ; my Firefox says it cannot connect to the server.

This probably explains why your code doesn't produce any expected output : if it relies on a geolocalition server, and that server doesn't work anymore...

As a sidenote : according to the index of [pear packages in the Networking section](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=16&catname=Networking), `Net_Geo` is not maintained anymore, and the last version was released in 2006-03-29 ; which is quite not a good sign...

If you can install PECL packages *(you'll probably need to be admin of your server)*, maybe the [GeoIP package](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) would interest you.

Comment: thanks for the answers.

But what are the parameters should I pass to "applicationName" and "alternateServerUrl"

Comment: YOu're welcome about the anser ;; sorry, I have absolutly no idea about what values you should use ;; I myself would probably not use that package, actually (it's quite old, it's not maintained since a long time, it generates a lot of notices, ...)